# SAPUI5 navigate back to start page

Tags: sapui5

I have a scenario with a start page (full page) from where user can navigate to Master-Detail1-Detail2. Forward navigation works fine, but when the user navigates back from detail1, he should get back to the start page. Also that works fine, but when the user then selects in the start page to move to master again, the screen jumps directly back to detail1 screen.

This is my controller for detail1.js:

```
onNavBack_det2: function(oEvent) {
    this.getRouter().navTo("app", {
    })
},
```

And the routing part in component.js:

```
                pattern: "split",
                name: "App",
                view: "App",
                viewId: "AppId",
                targetControl: "masterAppId",
                subroutes : [{  
                    pattern: "master",
                    name: "master",
                    view: "Master",
                    targetAggregation: "masterPages",
                    targetControl: "idAppControl",
```

I have tried to destroy the detail1.view then it navigates to an empty page. What I want is that when the user navigates to the start page again, all other views are initialized, so user really starts from the beginning. What am I missing or how can that be achieved?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Tim

App view looks like this so just the App:

```
<SplitApp id="idAppControl" mode="ShowHideMode"/>
```

So basically empty, from where the Overview page is called, which is the starting page with 2 tiles. Overview.js looks like this:

sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.extend("ZTRUKKI.controller.Overview, {

```
getRouter : function() {
    return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
},

toMove:function(){

this.getRouter().navTo("master", {
    from : "overview",
})
},

toDelivery:function(){

this.getRouter().navTo("master1", {
    from : "overview",
})
},
```

});

Comment: Have you tried to set the "clearAggregation" property of the Router?

Comment: what does your app view look like?

Comment: trying the clearAggregation property, not sure where to add it?